Question about ‘chazak ve-emotz’
Shalom.
I am aware this is a stupid question, but is ‘chazak ve-emotz’ - Be strong and of a good courage
 in doing mitzvot a general commandment, given to all, or was it only for Yehoshua Ha-Navi?
Thanks for your time.

Rashi explains that the commandments was 1) given to Yehoshua in the physical sense, i.e. warfare, 2) And it was said in reference to the Torah, as He states: ‘To preserve, to act in accordance with all the laws of the Torah.’
The Gemara in Berachos 32b explains, in line with what Rashi teaches, that  "Chazak VeOmetz - Be strong and of a good courage" refers to the observance of all of Torah.

do not deviate to the right or to the left, that you may succeed wherever you go” (Joshua 1:7). In this verse, observe refers to Torah study and do refers to good deeds (Maharsha); the apparently repetitive language is not extraneous. The Gemara derives: Be strong in Torah and be courageous in good deeds. (Sefaria-translation with commentary)


Thanks for this. A follow-up question: Is one obligated to bolster oneself in Torah and good deeds, or should that bolstering come from others?

"And G-d will give us all the good things that strengthen our hands to fulfill the Torah", as the Rambam writes

That’s brilliant - many thanks. Will accept the answer above. Blessings :)

You're welcome! Hatzlacha!

It is also said elsewhere  in what  is  a reference to everyone not only Yehoshua.
חֲ֭זַק וְיַאֲמֵ֣ץ לִבֶּ֑ךָ וְ֝קַוֵּ֗ה אֶל־יְהֹ said in Tehillim 27:14 is more likely to be the source the source of the common expression of chazak V'Amatz than the pesukim in Yeshoua  as it is more well known and said twice daily in Elul.
Rashi Tehillim 130:5 also quotes it in relation to being a part of the meaning of קויתי ה' קותה נפשי Tehillim 130:5 that also is not referring to only Yehoshua

It's only been said twice daily in most communities for less than 200 years. Is the expression really younger than that?
